Proof that $F(x,y) = f(x-y)$ is measurable
I have come up with a proof, that I am unsure about, for the following statement:

Lemma Let $f: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \overline {\Bbb R}$ be $\mathscr L^n$-measurable. Then the function $$F(x,y): \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \overline {\Bbb R}, (x,y) \mapsto f(x-y)$$ is $\mathscr L^{2n}$-measurable.

Notation.

$\mathscr L^n$ is the unique Carathéodory-Hahn extension of the volume function on disjoint $n$-dim intervals.
For measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ the product measure $\mu \times \nu$ is the unique Carathéodory-Hahn extension of $\lambda(A\times B) := \mu(A)\nu(B)$ on $\{A\times B\ |\ A\ \mu\text{-measurable and } B\ \nu\text{-measurable}\}$.
$f$ is $\mathscr L^n$-measurable if the preimage of open sets and $\{\pm \infty\}$ is $\mathscr L^n$-measurable.

Proof Define the following functions: $$\pi_x: \Bbb R^{2n} \rightarrow \Bbb R^n, (x_1, \dots, x_n, y_1, \dots, y_n) \mapsto (x_1, \dots, x_n)$$ $$\pi_y: \Bbb R^{2n} \rightarrow \Bbb R^n, (x_1, \dots, x_n, y_1, \dots, y_n) \mapsto (y_1, \dots, y_n)$$
Since $\pi_x, \pi_y$ are continuous in each coordinate, the maps are continuous. Hence the function $$g: \Bbb R^{2n} \rightarrow \Bbb R^n, (x,y) \mapsto \pi_x(x,y) - \pi_y(x,y) = x-y$$ is also continuous. As such, the composition $f\circ g = F$ is $\mathscr L^n$-measurable. $\square$
Question Is my reasoning for $g$ being continuous correct? Does it instantly follow that $F$ is measurable from this? Can the same reasoning be mutatis mutandis applied for showing that $F(x,y) = f(x)g(y)$?

No. The proof is wrong. Yes, $g$ is continuous, yes $f$ is Lebesgue measurable, but that does not mean $f\circ g$ is Lebesgue measurable. If you were merely speaking of Borel-measurability, then this argument would be fine. See Is composition of Lebesgue measurable function and addition Lebesgue measurable? for the proper way to argue this result.

@peek-a-boo Could you elaborate on what it means for a function to be Borel-measurable? I have not heard of this notion in my course on measure theory outside of measures being Borel.

Preimage of Borel sets are Borel.
